# Blazor bootstrap 5 modal: how to not bind a property to value?

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, blazor

In blazor I created a modal component like:

```
public bool CanCloseWithoutAction { get; set; } = false;

<div class="modal fade @modalClass" 
     data-bs-backdrop="@(CanCloseWithoutAction ? "":"static")" 
     data-bs-keyboard ="@(CanCloseWithoutAction ? "" : "false")" 
     aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     style="display:@modalDisplay; overflow-y: auto;">
```

So when CanCloseWithoutAction is true, in the browser I get:

```
<div class="modal fade show" data-bs-backdrop="" data-bs-keyboard="" 
     aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     style="display:block;; overflow-y: auto;">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable 
          modal-dialog-centered modal-xl " role="document">
```

but even when `data-bs-backdrop="" data-bs-keyboard=""` it still does not allow the user to close it on esc key or click elsewhere.

So how to bind in blazor so that when this parameter is true then I get

```
<div class="modal fade show" aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     style="display:block;; overflow-y: auto;">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-xl " 
          role="document">
```

without these two properties?

Comment: Is seems like there is no way to render on tag level conditional attributes in blazor. I've deleted wrong answer, if you really aware of copypasting you can render whole tag as markup string using @((MarkupString)YourVarOrProperty) syntax.

Comment: Why don't you use `"true"` instead of the empty string? The [default option values](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#options) are `true`, not `""`. The empty string is treated as `false` in JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [default option value](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#options) for both `backdrop` and `keyboard` is `true`. In JavaScript though, the empty string is [a falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and treated as `false` in a boolean expression.

The code should be changed to :

```
<div class="modal fade @modalClass" 
     data-bs-backdrop="@(CanCloseWithoutAction ? "true":"static")" 
     data-bs-keyboard ="@(CanCloseWithoutAction ? "true" : "false")" 
     aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     style="display:@modalDisplay; overflow-y: auto;">
```

if not

```
<div class="modal fade @modalClass" 
     data-bs-backdrop="@(CanCloseWithoutAction ? "true":"static")" 
     data-bs-keyboard ="@CanCloseWithoutAction" 
     aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     style="display:@modalDisplay; overflow-y: auto;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
@if (CanCloseWithoutAction) {
  // markup for can close
<div class="modal fade show" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" 
     aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     style="display:block;; overflow-y: auto;">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable 
          modal-dialog-centered modal-xl " role="document">
}
else {
   // markup for can't close
<div class="modal fade show" aria-modal="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
     style="display:block;; overflow-y: auto;">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable modal-dialog-centered modal-xl " 
          role="document" />
}
```

Comment: yep i did that also yesturday ;P  that should work but this is not what i wanted - should be possible to bind that also somehow ;D

Comment: You can resort to `BuildRenderTree` to do it.  I use it quite a bit -though it comes with a Microsoft Health Warning.  I have a Bootstrap Modal implementation coded that way.  Just make sure you use manual numbering.

Comment: can you maybe shareit? does fade in/out effects works in your solution also?